# Get an estimate on $L^{2}(0,1)$

Tags: normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Consider $f \in L^{2}(0,1)$ and $g \in L^{\infty}(0,1)$ such that

1. $ \text{lim} ~g(x) = 0 \ \ \text{when} \ \ x \to 0^{+};$
2. $g(x) > 0 \ \forall x \in (0,1)$;
3. $\text{lim}~\dfrac{g(x)}{x^{\alpha}} = N > 0,$ when $x \to 0^{+}$, $0 < \alpha < 1$

Moreover, suppose
$$
\int_{0}^{1}g(x)|f(x)|^{2} = M < \infty
$$
**Question:** Is it possible to get an estimate of the form
$$
\|f\|_{L^{2}(0,1)}^{2} \leq C \|gf\|_{L^{2}(0,1)}^{2} ?
$$

**My idea**
$$
\|gf\|_{L^{2}(0,1)}^{2} \leq \|g\|_{L^{\infty}(0,1)} \int_{0}^{1}g(x)|f(x)|^{2} = M\|g\|_{L^{\infty}(0,1)} 
$$
It is correct to write
$$
\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{2} = \dfrac{1}{|g(s)|}\int_{0}^{1}|g(s)||f(x)|^{2} dx
$$
But I can't do anything more than that :(

Comment: Conditon 3 is for some $\alpha$ fixed, or for all $\alpha$?

Comment: @Sebathon Any $\alpha$ between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Sebathon: This can only ever hold for one fixed $\alpha$ (why?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Think of a sequence of $f_n$ such that $\| f_n\|_2=1$ while $\|g f_n\|_2\to 0$. And you might as well assume $g(x)= x^{\alpha}$ : the question is at the origin, whatever happens elsewhere could create additional trouble, since you did not exclude a funky behavior somewhere else. For example around $x=\frac12$ you could have
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
x^{\alpha}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{|x-\frac12|}\right) & \textrm{ for }x\neq\frac12 \\
1 & \textrm{ for }x=\frac12\end{cases}
$$

So let us stick with the behavior near zero. It is equivalent to asking the same question with $f_n\geq0$, $\| f_n\|_1 =1$, $\| x^{2\alpha}f_n\|_1\to0$ (just take $g_n=\sqrt{f_n}$ for the $L^2$ case).

Let us try $f_n=\begin{cases} n & \textrm{when } x<\frac1n\\ 0 &\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}.$ We check that it works:
$$\int f_n \textrm{d} x =1,\quad \int_0^1 x^{2\alpha} f_n \textrm{d} x = \frac{1}{(2\alpha+1)n^{2\alpha}}\to0.$$

Comment: Thanks. Good job.